# systemctl error "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted "

Tags: docker, systemctl

I am not able to use `systemctl` commands in a Docker container I am getting:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

even after running container in privileged mode I am getting same error:

```
docker run --name my-container -d -it  --privileged=true dind /usr/sbin/init
```

And:

```
docker run -it --name my-container --privileged -d --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro my-image
```

Not working.

Comment: That's true, for the most part you can't use `systemctl` commands in Docker.  Containers rarely run a full init system and even more rarely the very heavyweight systemd; instead, a container just runs a single process in the foreground.

Comment: For the most part, yes this is uncommon, but this used to work by adding the privileged flag and making /sbin/init the PID 1 -- there are many legitimate uses for doing this.

Comment: Hello, can you expose what it is the Docker image that you are working on?, `centos`, `amazonlinux`, `debian, etc.